# How can I fix weird font behavior in IEEEtran when using TikZ graphdrawing library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, ieeetran, tikz-graphdrawing

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing} % needs luatex!
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract} \lipsum[1] \end{abstract}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

When compiling it with `pdflatex`, TikZ tells me to use `luatex`, apart from that standard fonts of IEEEtran are in place. But when I compile it with `luatex`, I'm losing IEEEtran standard fonts (Times is switched back to CM or the like).

Symptoms seem to be similar to [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427680/in-ieeetran-why-does-fontspec-package-automatically-change-the-font-type-once) issue but I'm not even using `fontspec`.

Has anybody an idea what went wrong and how I can manage to use graph drawing and keep IEEEtran fonts?

Thank you!

Comment: quite likely the ieee submission won't accept luatex anyway, you may want to use luatex in a separate document to draw your graph, and theninclude it as an image into the main document

Comment: @David: I tried, indeed, IEEEtran doesn't seem to like `luatex`. There are a few font shape warnings but is this a fundamental issue or could it be easily solved? However, thanks, including the figure as a PDF might be a good workaround.

Comment: @Mario It is a fundamental issue: if IEEE doesn't want LuaTeX and you need that to draw a diagram, then you need to compile the diagram separately. That is how it is 'easily solved'. The other options are to do your diagram without LuaTeX or to persuade IEEE to accept LuaTeX. The latter is, for practical purposes, likely as close to impossible as makes no odds. The former depends, of course, on your diagram, but it is hard to think it would be an easier option.

Comment: That is, you could change the fonts in LuaTeX, obviously - `fontspec` would be the usual way. So you can get them to match more-or-less what IEEE wants. But since they almost certainly won't then accept your submission, is there any point?

Comment: @Mario it is a policy not a technical issue. If the journal or conference that you are using IEEEtran for uses pdftex to process the publication, you making local changes so the file works with luatex will just break their publication process.

Comment: Thanks cfr and @David. I get that point, and I don't want to undermine the whole IEEE publication process with my request ;) Changing fonts is a thing that sounds awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LuaTeX seems to have trouble with fonts included by IEEEtran. Thanks to the explanations of David Carlisle and @cfr, I understand that this is supposed to be a more fundamental issue potentially impacting the whole IEEE publication process and should be solved by including figures as PDF files.

So, one comparably convenient workaround to that problem can be achieved with the [`standalone` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone), producing separate PDFs for each TikZ figure and include these PDF files in the main document the standard way via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Sorry for this comment but IMHO your answer would read much better if you would acknowledge the comments by David Carlisle and @cfr. Don't you think so?

Comment: Absolutely. Included my comment above now in my answer as well.